# I got this error output when I type 'make' to compile the 'dash-to-dock'

Tags: debian, dock, dash-shell

```
msgfmt -c po/de.po -o po/de.mo
make: msgfmt: No se encontró el programa
Makefile:51: recipe for target 'po/de.mo' failed
make: *** [po/de.mo] Error 127
```

can someone help me?

Answer (score 4):

Try to install gettext package:

```
apt-get install gettext
```